# Fastest way to compare dates: UNIX_TIMESTAMP or FROM_UNIXTIME or string

Tags: mysql, datetime

What is the fastest way to select rows with a field greater than a certain date?

```
WHERE date > FROM_UNIXTIME(12345)
```

or

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 12345
```

or

```
WHERE date > '2011-05-01 09:00:00'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slowest is:

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 12345
```

because the unix_timestamp function has to be called each time for every row, and an index on the date column, if present, won't be used. The others are almost equivalent:

```
WHERE date > FROM_UNIXTIME(12345)
WHERE date > '2011-05-01 09:00:00'
```

the function from_unixtime will be called only once, even the string will be parsed only once, it won't make any difference, but I prefer the last one as it is more readable.

Of course, don't forget to index your date column:

```
alter table tablename add index idx_date (date)
```